# Retrieving values from an unserialized MutableMap in JSON

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I stored a mutableMap as a JSON, and then retrieved it. But when trying to get any of the data every key returns null. I checked on the android developer debugger and I can see that GSON retrieved all the keys as if they were strings. Is it possible to store Maps with Integers as keys in a JSON? Or do I have to store it with Strings as keys instead?

This is the declaration of the variable

```
val mapYears: MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<MutableMap<String, Int>, Int>>>>
        = HashMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<MutableMap<String, Int>, Int>>>>()
```

And this is one example of the map I'm trying to store, it's basically a map of Years > Months > Days > Time

```
   "2022":{
      "1":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "2":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "3":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "4":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "5":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "6":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "7":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "8":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "9":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "10":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "11":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      },
      "12":{
         "1":{
            
         },
         "2":{
            
         },
         "3":{
            
         },
         "4":{
            
         },
         "5":{
            
         },
         "6":{
            
         },
         "7":{
            
         },
         "8":{
            
         },
         "9":{
            
         },
         "10":{
            
         },
         "11":{
            
         },
         "12":{
            
         },
         "13":{
            
         },
         "14":{
            
         },
         "15":{
            
         },
         "16":{
            
         },
         "17":{
            
         },
         "18":{
            
         },
         "19":{
            
         },
         "20":{
            
         },
         "21":{
            
         },
         "22":{
            
         },
         "23":{
            
         },
         "24":{
            
         },
         "25":{
            
         },
         "26":{
            
         },
         "27":{
            
         },
         "28":{
            
         },
         "29":{
            
         },
         "30":{
            
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is how I store the map:

```
 val stepsRecord: String = Gson().toJson(mapYears)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("stepsRecord", stepsRecord);
        editor.commit();
```

And this is how I retrieve the map:

```
   val mapYearMonthsAny: MutableMap<*, *>? = Gson().fromJson(mapYearMonthsString, MutableMap::class.java)
   return mapYearMonthsAny as MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<MutableMap<String, Int>, Int>>>>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Should I use another unserializing method? Thanks in advance for all the answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

The problem isn't on the serializing of the item but on the unserializing. You can specify the type of the object you're retrieving like this

```
 val type: Type = object : TypeToken<MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<Int, MutableMap<MutableMap<String, Int>, Int>>>>?>() {}.type
```

Then Gson changes the type accordingly, so you can use Integer keys on the map or whatever you want if you specify the type as a parameter.

```
val mapYearMonthsAny: MutableMap<*, *>? = Gson().fromJson(mapYearMonthsString, type)
```